# Algorithm / function for finding all combinations of a list where all items in the list are used in each combination

Tags: python, list, algorithm, combinations, permutation

I have a list of items in where each item has a certain size.
I need to group the list into smaller sublists where the total size of the items in each sublist can not exceed a certain max size (the order does not matter and only one instance of each element can exists in the sublists).
I want to end up with as few sublists as possible.

For example, if I have this list:

`l = ['A': 0.75, 'B': 0.50, 'C': 0.15, 'D': 0.20, 'E': 0.30]` and a max size of 1.0,
the ideal solution would be two sublists, fx. `['A', 'C'] = 0.90` and `['B', 'D', 'E'] = 1.0`

Is there a way for me to check / is there any algorithm that checks all combinations of the list (where each element is used in each combination) that I can use to find this optimal solution of as few sublists as possible?

Comment: Seems like a bin packing problem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem . It is NP-hard but there are reasonable heuristics which can be implemented in Python.

Comment: This is a dynamic programming problem, you can go to understand the idea of dynamic programming algorithm.